# Commuting operators' eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

So, one of my homework problems reads the following

> Let $A$ and $B$ be commuting operators and $| \psi_i \rangle$ denote the eigenfunctions of $A$. Show that $\langle \psi_i |B| \psi_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$

I have tried to approach the solution in the following way:

Since $A$ and $B$ commute, we have, for any vectors $| \psi_i \rangle$ and $| \psi_j \rangle$, $$\langle \psi_i |AB| \psi_j \rangle=\langle \psi_i |BA| \psi_j \rangle$$
Let $\lambda_i$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ for each vector $|\psi_i \rangle$. Therefore, solving the above equation, we get-
$$\lambda_i^*\langle \psi_i |B| \psi_j \rangle=\lambda_j\langle \psi_i |B| \psi_j \rangle$$
This leaves us with- $$(\lambda_i^*-\lambda_j)\langle \psi_i |B| \psi_j \rangle=0$$
From here, I have certain questions on proceeding further-

1. Is it to be assumed that $A$ is hermitian? If so, then since $\lambda_i^*=\lambda_i$, so for $i \neq j$, we have $\langle \psi_i|B|\psi_j \rangle=0$. But which theorem states that $A$ can,be considered Hermitian here.
2. If $i=j$, how do I go further and prove  $\langle \psi_i|B|\psi_j \rangle=1$

Comment: The problem looks to be incorrectly stated. For a general operator $\hat{B}$, you don't expect its matrix elements to be $\delta_{ij}$. Perhaps they mean $B_{ij}$? Also, in your point 2 you have identified a very important point: if you have degenerate eigenvalues, then the prove becomes significantly more involved.

Comment: Yes, the problem statement seems incorrect. Even if hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ commute, it does not mean that any eigenbasis of $A$ is an eigenbasis of $B$. Commutation only guarantees the existence of a common eigenbasis: $(1,1,0)$ is an eigenvector of $\mathrm{diagonal}(1,1,-1)$ but not an eigenvector of $\mathrm{diagonal}(1,-1,1)$, despite the fact that diagonal matrices commute.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of the question is perhaps if it meant to say that the operator $B$ commutes with *every* operator $A$, in which case $B$ would have to be the identity.

Comment: A lot of details seems amiss. If this problem is from a book, kindly post the reference. I do not see how else this can be true. Also, at least there should be a factor with the delta function (if at all it can be true) since nothing fixes the normalisation of the B expectation values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $\langle\psi_i|B|\psi_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ does not seem right (unless $B$ is the identity, which would make this a strange question). To answer your questions in order:

1. Not *necessarily*, although if this is a homework on quantum mechanics it would make sense that the operators in question correspond to observables and so *must* be Hermitian.
2. This will only be true if $B$ is the identity matrix, since every state vector is an eigenvector of the identity operator with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. In the event that this *is* what the question is asking, you will just find $$\langle\psi_i|B|\psi_i\rangle=1\cdot\langle\psi_i|\psi_i\rangle=1\cdot 1=1,$$ since $\langle\psi_i|\psi_i\rangle$ is the norm of $\psi_i$, which, if normalised, is just $1$.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer to your question and to the confusion in the comments is that since $A$ and $B$ commute they are simultanously diagonalizable. Therefore your question is true up to some constants $\lambda_j$ in front of the $\delta_{ij}$. Your proof is essential correct and does not require hermiticity.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems with the problem as stated:

- as @secavara mentioned, having a common basis of eigenvectors is not enough. We would certainly require the $|\psi_i\rangle$ to be common eigenvectors.
- Demanding $\langle\psi_i|B|\psi_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ is certainly too much, probably it was meant to be that $B$ is diagonal in this basis.

As an example of where things go horribly wrong, take $A$ the identity matrix. This commutes with any $B$, and every vector is an eigenvector. Let's just take the standard basis and denote it $|i\rangle$. In this basis, $\langle\psi_i|B|\psi_j\rangle = \langle i|B|j\rangle$ is just the $i,j$ component $B_{ij}$ of $B$, which can be whatever you want.